# У меня проблема с поиском программиста Битрикс

Tags: обсуждение

Скажите пожалуйста, тут выкладываются резюме тех, кто ищет для себя работу? Мне посоветовали воспользоваться вашим сайтом. При необходимости могу выслать ссылку на нашу вакансию и описанием обязанностей. Спасибо.

Comment: @nick_n_a такое и для Меты оффтопиком является.

Comment: В русской версии я не видел раздел "работа", в английской раздел тут http://stackoverflow.com/jobs если владеете английским - можете разместить.

Comment: можно "вырастить" сотрудника .Нанять студента 4-5 курса и за год он дорастёт до программиста битрикс

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что является недопустимым для данной площадки.

Answer (score 2):

алгоритм поиска:

1. на каждой странице сайта есть ссылка «[Метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags)».
2. в поле поиска вписываете интересующую вас тему («битрикс») и просматриваете все найденные метки, начиная с «[битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81)».
3. на таких страницах есть ссылка «[Лучшие участники](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81/topusers)».
4. просматриваете профили участников. там есть список лучших сообщений (по центру) и (возможно) контактная информация, которой участник захотел поделиться (вверху справа).

Answer (score 1):

Этот сайт не предназначен для поиска работы или работников. Однако, если есть интересующие участники и они в открытом виде указали контакты для связи в своём профиле (или даже написали, что ищут работу), то можно попробовать с ними связаться.

Comment: @nick_n_a, на ruSO платной рекламы нет. Да и бесплатной пока тоже по сути - только баннеры самого ruSO крутятся.

Comment: На англ. SO можно же разместить вакансию. Стоит конечно кой-чего.